# How do I add a bullet symbol in TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, special-characters, textview

I have a TextView and I want to add a bullet symbol in my text through XML. Is it possible?

Answer (score 477, accepted):

You have to use the right [character encoding](http://xahlee.info/js/html_chars.html) to accomplish this effect. You could try with `&#8226;`

#### Update

Just to clarify: use `setText("\u2022 Bullet");` to add the bullet programmatically. `0x2022 = 8226`

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_references) helped me.

Comment: This is the right answer. More correct than pasting the bullet in.

Comment: @Benny, This is not working if I set text programmatically. textView.setText("&#8226; hello");

Comment: @DwivediJi No, but the question was how to add it in XML. If you have a new question - feel free to ask :-)

Comment: Just to clarify: use `setText("\u2022 Bullet");` to add the bullet programmatically.  `0x2022 = 8226`

Comment: &#x00b7; by using this I got a smaller size bullet

Comment: Here are character code to these different style of bullets:

`• = \u2022,   ● = \u25CF,   ○ = \u25CB,   ▪ = \u25AA,   ■ = \u25A0,   □ = \u25A1,   ► = \u25BA`

Comment: For Android: **In XML>>>** `&#8226;` and **In Java>>>** `\u2022`

Comment: &#8226; vs • in XML, which one to use and why?

Answer (score 81):

This worked for me:

```
<string name="text_with_bullet">Text with a \u2022</string>
```

Answer (score 33):

Copy paste: •. I've done it with other weird characters, such as ◄ and ►.

**Edit:** [here](http://code.google.com/p/droidstack/source/browse/res/layout/question.xml)'s an example. The two `Button`s at the bottom have `android:text="◄"` and `"►"`.

Comment: The problem is when line wraps. It will not indent a 2nd line

Comment: just use a linear layout with orientation horizontal, first textview with "Icon and Space" second :=) the text, => all intended

Answer (score 21):

Prolly a better solution out there somewhere, but this is what I did.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TableRow>    
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="•"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="First line"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>    
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="•"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Second line"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

It works like you want, but a workaround really.

Answer (score 12):

You may try [BulletSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan.html) as described in Android docs.

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with\nBullet point");
string.setSpan(new BulletSpan(40, color, 20), 10, 22, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[image: Result]

Comment: What about using bulletRadius property on before API 28?

Comment: any method to set bullet size?

Comment: @UsmanRana yes you can try replacing 20 i.e. the third argument in the BulletSpan constructor with your  preferred size, which represent radius.  BulletSpan(int gapWidth, int color, int bulletRadius)

Answer (score 8):

Another best way to add bullet in any text view is stated below two steps:

First, create a drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <!--set color of the bullet-->
   <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/> //set color of bullet

    <!--set size of the bullet-->
   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then add this drawable in textview and set its pedding by using below properties

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/bullet"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how i ended up doing it.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_bullet_point" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Your text"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

and the code for drawbale/circle.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:innerRadius="0dp"
  android:shape="ring"
  android:thickness="5dp"
  android:useLevel="false">

 <solid android:color="@color/black1" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 5):

With Unicode we can do it easily, but if want to change color of bullet, I tried with colored bullet image and set it as `drawableStart` and it worked

```
<TextView     
    android:text="Hello bullet"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/bulleticon" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since android doesnt support `<ol>, <ul> or <li>` html elements, I had to do it like this

```
<string name="names"><![CDATA[<p><h2>List of Names:</h2></p><p>&#8226;name1<br />&#8226;name2<br /></p>]]></string>
```

if you want to maintain custom space then use `</pre> tag`

Answer (score 0):

(almost) all of the options are about using `html` tags.

you can use drawables for your TextView **if it has only one line of text.**

something like this:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_with_bullet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_desired_bullet_icon" />
```

and add your desired bullet drawable in SVG. it literally takes no space and makes you free of adding complicated `string literals`. you can also download the SVG file for a bullet point in [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bullet_(typography).svg)

Answer (score 0):

I create this extensión function in Kotlin

```kotlin
fun TextView.addBulletPoints(bulletSymbol: Char = '•') {
    //•‣⁃∙◎◦⦾⦿
    val lines = text?.split("\n") ?: emptyList()
    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()

    for (line in lines) {
        builder.append("$bulletSymbol ")
        builder.append(line.trim())
        builder.append("\n")
    }

    text = builder
}
```

or alternative API 24 upper

```kotlin
fun TextView.addBulletPoints(bulletGapWidth: Int = 32, bulletRadius: Int = 12, color: Int = currentTextColor) {
    val lines = text?.split("\n") ?: emptyList()
    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()

    for (line in lines) {
        val start = builder.length
        builder.append(line.trim())
        builder.setSpan(BulletSpan(bulletGapWidth, color, bulletRadius), start, builder.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        builder.append("\n")
    }

    text = builder
}
```