# Show a bulleted list from Strings.xml file in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to show a bulleted list contents which is resided in strings.xml file as an array elements. Then the problem is that how to convert the array elements in Html List format? Can any one suggest any solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429546/android-how-to-add-bullet-symbol-in-textview/3429643#3429643

Comment: Check this link for better way 

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992794/how-to-add-bulleted-list-to-android-application>

Answer (score 1):

I just put the symbol directly into the strings.xml without any codes or anything:

```
<string name="msg_sms_no_note">• Notes and attachments will not be sent.</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the approach suggested by some of the answers in this thread of prepending the bullet unicode character (i.e. `\u2022`) to each of the Strings in the String array: You don't get proper indentation when one or more Strings in the String array span multiple lines. What you get is formatting as follows:

[image: Formatting with the bullet unicode character]

In order to get proper indentation, you're better using [BulletSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan). In doing so, you'll get formatting as follows:

[image: Formatting with BulletSpan]

To use [BulletSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan), you need to create a [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder) instance and append each String in your String array to this [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder) instance. As you append each String, call the [setSpan(what:start:end:flags:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method on the [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder) instance passing in a [BulletSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan) instance for the `what` parameter. You can find an example of this in the `appendBulletSpan(...)` Kotlin extension function located [here](https://github.com/TazkiyaTech/android-utils/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/tazkiyatech/utils/display/SpannableStringBuilderExtensions.kt).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most elegant way of doing this is to load a `WebView` and put your string in it. this way, you use the common ul/li convention and you can style it at your leisure with CSS.

Comment: Where would you add the css styling for this?

Comment: This is a bad idea Webview sucks up way too much memory and is flawed in many ways.  Use the &#8226; instead of the actual symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Use the unicode escape sequence "\u2022" in strings.xml

like so:

```
<string name="menu_new_trip_desc">View them in: \n\u2022 Table
```