# show text in textview by pointwise in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to show string in textview by pointwise . To be more precise , I want to show the text as described in the following image in an textview .

[image]

How can I do that ? Can you tell an way to show the text in the above image in textview in android ?

Answer (score 1):

See this page to added bulleted lists: [How to add bulleted list to android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992794/how-to-add-bulleted-list-to-android-application)

Also, this page may be helpful: [How do I add a bullet symbol in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429546/how-do-i-add-a-bullet-symbol-in-textview)

All you need to do is add a HTML Character: http://xahlee.info/js/html_chars.html