# u\2022 not displaying in textview that retrieves from json

Tags: android, json, textview

*I had found an answer that we can use bullets in textview by adding u\2022 with the text.
Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429643/4919237*

When i added this code through XML it displays fine in TextView

[image]

and When i try to display bullet through json it doesnt display bullet ,instead it displays the text u\2022 itself.

[image]

my receiving Json format is

```
{"description":"\\u2022first one\\n\\u2022second one edited\\n"}
```

**please help me to reslove my problem.**

Comment: set text like this:
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(your description));

Comment: you can use `Html.fromHtml` when `setText` method calling

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya : still the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At First , You can check `Html.fromHtml`  & remove one `\` .

> Html.formHtml method takes an Html.TagHandler and an Html.ImageGetter
>   as arguments as well as the text to parse.

```
YourTextViewObj.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your String"));
```

**FYI**

***Currently android seems support the following HTML tags to be rendered on TextView.***

[image]

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu Move ahead

Answer (score 1):

You can set text using Html.fromHtml like

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(your description));
```

Comment: remove one \ from string