# In firebase database, can i store bullet point, other symbol? If yes, how?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, i want to save blog post in firebase realtime database and want to upload my post with symbol like this

[image]

Is there any way? I didn't found any. My code

```
mPost.setText(fromHtml(dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue().toString()));

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            return Html.fromHtml(html);
        }
    }
```

for `<ul><li>Item 1</li><br><li>Item 2</li></ul>`

**Output:**

Item 1
Item 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html string to upload it.

For example if you want to upload an unordered list:

```
Upload following string in firebase db
"stringVal" : "<b>Title</b><br><br>&#8226; item1<br>&#8226;item2<br>&#8226;item3"
```

And display it in android (using java) like this:

```
TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo);
foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(<String from firebase db>));
```

Output:

**Title**

- item1
- item2
- item3

Reference : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429546/how-do-i-add-a-bullet-symbol-in-textview)

Comment: I have added my question. Please have a look.

Comment: I have changed the answer. Have a look.

Comment: I accept this answer but never forget to menstion that Html.formHtml(String) is depricated. We should use it with Html.formHtml(String,flag)